# cannot write mode RGBA as BMP pytesser

Tags: python, image, text

I'm use [PyTesser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyTesser) to get text from image. It's mostly working fine but in some cases I get this error:

```
cannot write mode RGBA as BMP
```

Images have no problem and is fine and same only text is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i say that , must resize the image 
you can use plugins for edit image size before use it and read it , plugin like pil
hope to work for you

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem -- issue was the transparency. (converting rbgy to rbg) Adding white background fixed it.

```
im = Image.open(C:\image.png)
bg = Image.new("RGB", im.size, (255,255,255))
bg.paste(im,im)
print image_to_string(bg)
```

Answer (score 1):

change size of your image , check it
sometimes problem is with small images

Comment: yes . it is true , i change image size and it work , but it is a problem , is way to fix it ?